# Nginx config for symfony on ubuntu

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, fpm

I want to setup symfony with nginx and this config is working fine

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /src/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_access.log;
}
```

However i also want that on my server i should also be able to access files via app_dev.php and app_test.php as well

so far with above config.   `http://127.0.0.1/api/check` is working fine

but i also want

`http://127.0.0.1/app_dev.php/api/check` and `http://127.0.0.1/app_test.php/api/check` to work as well.

Currently its gives me 404 error

Comment: Does it work with `http://127.0.0.1/app.php/api/check`?

Comment: @Phil no it dont work , because the look like all the urls are automatically prefixed with app.php `try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;`. i tried chaging it to app_dev and app_test and it works fine as well but they dont work all together ,  with apache2 it works , bow now i want to use nginx only

Comment: You might need to add `fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;`. See https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/#fastcgi-params. You also haven't enabled php-fpm for anything other that `app.php`

Comment: @Phil You mean , i need to delete the line `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` and use `fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;` , also i tried chaging the regex to use app_dev as well but still i get 404 error

Comment: Honestly, I don't know as I'm a lousy sysadmin. You might get some traction over at https://serverfault.com if you can't get an answer here.

Comment: @Phil  com on Phil, i  have high hopes from person with 93k rep :)

Comment: Hey, if it was an Apache question, I could probably sort you out but I never used NGINX back in the day and now I only do automated deploys :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your using this for development you can list each **file** *(Environment)* in a `capturing group` `()` and separate with `|` which basically means "or".

```
location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|app_test)\.php(/|$) {
    ....
}
```

It is important not to use this example on a production server, as it is completely **unsecure**.

On a production server your current `conf`, is correct to only allow `app.php`.

Comment: Just for clarification you will need to restart `nginx` after making the changes.

Answer (score 0):

For more information you can use description from [symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx) and [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/symfony/#secure-symfony-3-x-2-x) official docs.

As you can see you should add some lines into your nginx conf file:

```
location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    ...
}
```

In case you also need app_test.php, then it should be changed a little bit. Just by including the file name:

```
location ~ ^/(app_dev|app_test)\.php(/|$) {
    ...
}
```

But please have a note:

> In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or app_test.php

Also it would be better to have following configuration before `error_log ...`:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: Did you do restart/reload of nginx?